# Magento 2: Round up foreign currency. How to do it?

Tags: magento2, currency, multicurrency, rounding, currency-rates

In Magento 2, how do we show prices in other currencies than the base currency rounded up?

For example, when foreign currencies are calculated using today's exchange rate, the price may be shown as $14.40. I want that to show as $15. How do I do that?

Thanks! :_)

Answer (score 3):

> vendor/magento/framework/pricing/amount/AmountFactory.php

```
public function create($amount, array $adjustmentAmounts = [])
{
    $amountModel = $this->objectManager->create(
        self::DEFAULT_PRICE_AMOUNT_CLASS,
        [
            'amount' => **round($amount)**,
            'adjustmentAmounts' => $adjustmentAmounts
        ]
    );

    if (!$amountModel instanceof \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            get_class($amountModel) . ' doesn\'t implement \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface'
        );
    }

    return $amountModel;
}
```

Comment: That is nice but not enough: cart lines, grand total, checkout are still displaying the decimals. Working on a more thorough solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211894/7773

Comment: @saachi working for me

Comment: @nicolallias thank you for suggesting other solution