# Magento 2 : Can We Convert Price Into Ceil Price

Tags: checkout, price, knockoutjs, magento2.1.6, grand-total

I have setup multi store view with multiple currency. Everything is working as expected.

Now, I  got requirement to convert all prices into ceil. **(e.g, SR20.02 = SR21)**. For this task, I have developed my own module on which I have override `Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount` and `Magento\Tax\Block\Item\Price\Renderer` and converted into ceil.
I also have overrided `price-utils.js` for knockout js file rendering in summary.
Everything is working correctly except grandtotal. I am not getting expected grandtotal.

In `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount`

Method overrided:

```
 /**
 * Format price value
 *
 * @param float $amount
 * @param bool $includeContainer
 * @param int $precision
 * @return float
 */
public function formatCurrency(
    $amount,
    $includeContainer = true,
    $precision = 0 
) {
    return $this->priceCurrency->format($amount, $includeContainer, $precision);
}
```

in \Magento\Tax\Block\Item\Price\Renderer

Method overrided:

```
 public function formatPrice($price)
{
    $item = $this->getItem();
    if ($item instanceof QuoteItem) {
        return $this->priceCurrency->format(
            $price,
            true,
            0,
            $item->getStore()
        );
    } elseif ($item instanceof OrderItem) {
        return $item->getOrder()->formatPrice($price);
    } else {
        return $item->getOrderItem()->getOrder()->formatPrice($price);
    }
}
```

I need help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Late but may be useful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144749/magento-2-round-up-foreign-currency-how-to-do-it try to round the amount in amountfactory

Comment: I endend up to a pretty neat module https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price which have been through all these problems (and some others)

Comment: Great work... @nicolallias It's look adorable and very useful module for such requirements

Comment: yup, that guy definitively merits a beer :)

Comment: Yes definitely :)